# how to use route to view static apidoc page with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, api-doc, static-pages

I am currently using http://apidocjs.com/ as my laravel apidoc because I am just used to it before.

to view the apidoc, each time I have to drag the `index.html` into the browser which is quite annoying.

Is it possible to make it into a static page so people I am sharing the apidoc with can just generate the doc then go to the route.

I tried something like...putting my `apidoc` folder under `public` folder of the application and also tried adding a route such as

```
Route::get('/apidoc', function(){
    return File::get(public_path() . '/apidoc/index.html');
});
```

Both of them didn't work the `index.html` cannot load the `css` and `js` because in `index.html` the source url is something like `vendor/polyfill.js` which then tried to go `localhost:8000/vendor/polyfill.js` but actually the url should be something like `localhost:8000/apidoc/vendor/polyfill.js`

Does anyone know how to easily fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "cheat" a little bit by registering the vendor routes as well:

```
Route::get('vendor/{any}', function ($any) {
    abort_unless(is_readable(public_path("apidoc/vendor/$any")), 404);
    return File::get(public_path("apidoc/vendor/$any")); 
})->where('any', ".*");

Route::get('apidoc', function(){
    return File::get(public_path() . '/apidoc/index.html');
});
```

Of course the ideal solution is if you actually manage to change the template you use for index.html to use relative and not absolute paths (i.e. change all `<link href='/vendor...'>` to `<link href='vendor...'>` so the file can automatically request the correct resource.

Comment: I get what you meant, but somehow still getting errors for getting files :(

Comment: it's a good trick, I will try figuring out the rest of 404 errors.  Thanks thanks a lot ^_^, the thing is the `index.html` template is generated by other services

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('apidoc', function(){
return File::get(public_path() . '/apidoc/index.html');
});
```

I hope to help someone.

To solve the 400 files not found issue, the apiDocjs installation is in the public folder, it's just a matter of changing the name of the folder where you make the request for the file search.

In my case I'm using Laravel for an API and the file paths (img, docs) always go to the api/assets/{filename} path.

Now just install apiDoc inside a folder called api and you're done!

[image: the structure of the files is as follows]

the structure of the files is as follows